# No selenium sessionId in setUp method in phpunit tests

Tags: selenium, phpunit

Trying to launch some selenium calls in setUp method of test case, I am getting errors like:

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?
```

Looks like phpunit does not provide selenium sessionId in setUp method (but, strangely,  calls to open() method in the same setUp  are working). Any way to convince phpunit to provide that variable?

Using phpunit 3.7.24 and selenium 2.35.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $this->start(); before your selenium calls